# React Native Flatlist extremely slow

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using react native's Flatlist, but it's extremely slow and my item list is small (about 20 items maximum). I'm using Native Base, and the thing is that when I want to set a "selected item" style, it takes about 3 or 4 seconds to trigger

I already read about 10 articles about how to optimize my Flatlist, and I have already implemented some of the optimizations, like limiting the render batch, etc., but definitely is not enough, when I click an item to change it's style keeps taking a long time to render, I don't think it's normal to have such a big delay on a small list. I also tried rendering with another class but is the same, even if using PureComponent

```
export default class Example extends React.Component {

closeDrawer () {
  this.drawer._root.close()
};

openDrawer () {
this.drawer._root.open()
};

constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       global.home_signals_url = "https://teosapp-testing.azurewebsites.net/api/ForexSignal/GetHome";
       global.history_signals_url = "https://teosapp-testing.azurewebsites.net/api/ForexSignal/GetHistory";
       this.state = {
             dataSourceHomeSignals: [],
             dataSourceHistorySignals: [],
             isFetching: false,
             showToast: false,
             Textdata:[],
             isReady: false,
             notification: {},
             selectedSignal: this.props.navigation.state.params.id
       };   
       this.isActiveSignal = this.isActiveSignal.bind(this);
       this.selectItem = this.selectItem.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount = async() => {
  await Font.loadAsync({
    Roboto: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
    Roboto_medium: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf')
  })
  this.setState({ isReady: true })
}

getHomeSignals() {
  this.setState({ isFetching: true }, function() { 
    const url = global.home_signals_url;
     fetch(url, { 
      method: 'GET', 
      headers: new Headers({
        'Authorization': '*****', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      })
    }).then((response)=>response.json())
               .then((responseJson)=> {
                 this.setState({
                   dataSourceHomeSignals : responseJson.Signals,
                   isFetching: false
                 })
                })
                .catch((error)=> {
                  console.log(error);
                }) 
   });
}

getHistorySignals() {
  this.setState({ isFetching: true }, function() { 
    const url = global.home_signals_url;
     fetch(url, { 
      method: 'GET', 
      headers: new Headers({
        'Authorization': '*****', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      })
    }).then((response)=>response.json())
               .then((responseJson)=> {
                 this.setState({
                   dataSourceHistorySignals : responseJson.Signals,
                   isFetching: false
                 })                     
                })
                .catch((error)=> {
                  console.log(error);
                }) 
   });
}

onRefreshHome() {
  this.getHomeSignals();
}

onRefreshHistory() {
  this.getHistorySignals();
}

signalStatusBG(status) {
  switch(status) {
    case 'Programada':
      return styles.orangeBG;
    case 'Activa':
      return styles.blueBG;
    case 'Ganada':
      return styles.greenBG;
    case 'Cancelada':
      return styles.grayBG;
    default:
      return styles.orangeBG;
  }
}

signalStatusBorder(status) {
  switch(status) {
    case 'Programada':
      return styles.orangeBorder;
    case 'Activa':
      return styles.blueBorder;
    case 'Ganada':
      return styles.greenBorder;
    case 'Cancelada':
      return styles.grayBorder;
    default:
      return styles.orangeBorder;
  }
}

isActiveSignal(index) {
  if(index == this.state.selectedSignal){
    return styles.selectedSignalStyle;
  }
}

isCardSelected(index) {
  if(index == this.state.selectedSignal){
    return styles.chosenItem;
  }
}

selectItem(index) {
  this.setState({selectedSignal: index})
}

_renderItem = ({item, index}) => (
  <MyListItem
       item={item}
       index={index}
       isActiveSignal={this.isActiveSignal}
       selectItem={this.selectItem}
       selectedSignal={this.state.selectedSignal}
  />
);

_keyExtractor = (item, index) => index.toString();

renderItem = ({item, index})=> {
  if (index == 100) {
    return null;
  }

  return (

    <TouchableOpacity          
      onPress={() => this.setState({selectedSignal: index})}>
      <LinearGradient
      colors={['#008696', '#006396', '#192f6a']}
      start={[0,1]}
      end={[1,0]}
      style={[{margin: 10, borderRadius: 5, marginBottom: 10, marginRight: 15, marginLeft: 15, marginTop: 15}, this.isActiveSignal(index), this.signalStatusBorder(item.StatusDisplayName)]}
      >
        <CardItem style={[{backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)', paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight:0}, this.isCardSelected(index)]}>
          <Grid>
            <Col style={{flex: 0.35, paddingRight: 15, borderRightWidth: 0.5, borderColor: '#fff'}}>
              <Item style={{borderBottomWidth: 0}}>
                <Image
                  source={require('./assets/flag.png')}
                  style={styles.leftFlag}
                />
                <Image
                  source={require('./assets/flag-en.png')}
                  style={styles.rightFlag}
                />
                <Text style={styles.currencyText}>{item.DisplayName}</Text>
              </Item>

              <Item style={{borderBottomWidth: 0}}>
                <Item style={{borderBottomWidth: 0, flexDirection: 'row', textAlign: 'center'}}>
                <Image
                  source={require('./assets/arrow-down.png')}
                  style={styles.arrow}
                />
                <Text style={styles.typeText}>{item.TypeDisplayName}</Text>
                </Item>                    
              </Item>
              <Item style={{borderBottomWidth: 0, textAlign: 'left', justifyContent: 'flex-start', flexDirection: 'column'}}>                    
                <Text style={styles.bgText}>{item.ExecutionTypeDisplayName}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.spacedText}>Duración: Day</Text>
                <Text style={styles.spacedText}>Caducidad: <Text style={styles.smallData}>{item.ExpirationDate}</Text></Text>
              </Item>
            </Col>
            <Col style={{flex: 0.65, paddingLeft: 5, paddingRight: 5}}>
              <Item style={{borderBottomWidth: 0}}>
                <Text style={[styles.statusText, this.signalStatusBG(item.StatusDisplayName)]}>{item.StatusDisplayName}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.dateText}>{item.ModifiedDate}</Text>
              </Item>                  

              <Item style={{borderBottomWidth: 0}}>
              <Grid>
                <Col style={{flex: 0.5, paddingLeft: 1, paddingRight: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
                <Item style={{borderBottomWidth: 0, alignItems:'flex-start', marginTop: 12}}>                    
                <Item style={{borderBottomWidth: 0, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems:'flex-start'}}>
                <Button
                  style={{
                    paddingTop: 0, 
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)', 
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                    alignItems:'flex-start', 
                    textAlign: 'left', 
                    marginBottom: 1,
                    marginTop:0,
                    elevation:0,
                    paddingLeft: 0,

                  }}
                  onPress={() => {
                  let { Textdata } = this.state;
                  Textdata[index] = item.Entry;
                  this.copyValue(JSON.stringify(this.state.Textdata[index]))
                }}>
                  <Text style={styles.valueBoxLabel}><Icon style={styles.miniIcon} active name='log-in' />  Entrada</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.valueBox}>{item.Entry}   <Icon style={styles.miniIcon} active name='copy' /></Text>                      
                  </Button> 
                  <Text style={styles.smallData}>Texto auxiliar</Text>
                </Item>                                     
                </Item>

              <Item style={{borderBottomWidth: 0, alignItems:'flex-start'}}>
                <Item style={{borderBottomWidth: 0, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems:'flex-start'}}>
                <Button
                  style={{
                    paddingTop: 0, 
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)', 
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                    alignItems:'flex-start', 
                    textAlign: 'left', 
                    marginBottom: 1,
                    marginTop:0,
                    elevation:0,
                  }}
                  onPress={() => {
                  let { Textdata } = this.state;
                  Textdata[index] = item.StopLoss;
                  this.copyValue(JSON.stringify(this.state.Textdata[index]))
                }}>
                  <Text style={[styles.valueBoxLabel]}><Icon style={styles.miniIcon} active name='remove-circle-outline' />  Salida</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.valueBox}>{item.StopLoss}   <Icon style={styles.miniIcon} active name='copy' /></Text>
                  </Button>
                  <Text style={styles.smallData}>Texto auxiliar</Text>
                </Item>                    
              </Item>
                </Col>
                <Col style={{flex: 0.5, paddingLeft: 1, paddingRight: 1}}>
                <Item style={{borderBottomWidth: 0, alignItems:'flex-start'}}>
                <Item style={{borderBottomWidth: 0, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems:'flex-start'}}>
                <Button
                  style={{
                    paddingTop: 0, 
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)', 
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                    alignItems:'flex-start', 
                    textAlign: 'left', 
                    marginBottom: 1,
                    marginTop:0,
                    elevation:0,
                  }}
                  onPress={() => {
                  let { Textdata } = this.state;
                  Textdata[index] = item.TakeProfitOne;
                  this.copyValue(JSON.stringify(this.state.Textdata[index]))
                }}>
                  <Text style={styles.valueBoxLabel}><Icon style={styles.miniIcon} active name='checkmark-circle-outline' />  TP-1</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.valueBox}>{item.TakeProfitOne}   <Icon style={styles.miniIcon} active name='copy' /></Text>
                  </Button>
                </Item>                  
                </Item>

                  <Item style={{borderBottomWidth: 0, alignItems:'flex-start'}}>
                    <Item style={{borderBottomWidth: 0, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems:'flex-start'}}>
                    <Button
                  style={{
                    paddingTop: 0, 
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)', 
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                    alignItems:'flex-start', 
                    textAlign: 'left', 
                    marginBottom: 1,
                    marginTop:0,
                    elevation:0,
                  }}
                  onPress={() => {
                  let { Textdata } = this.state;
                  Textdata[index] = item.TakeProfitTwo;
                  this.copyValue(JSON.stringify(this.state.Textdata[index]))
                }}>
                      <Text style={styles.valueBoxLabel}><Icon style={styles.miniIcon} active name='checkmark-circle-outline' />  TP-2</Text>
                      <Text style={styles.valueBox}>{item.TakeProfitTwo}   <Icon style={styles.miniIcon} active name='copy' /></Text>
                      </Button>
                    </Item>                    
                  </Item>

                  <Item style={{borderBottomWidth: 0, alignItems:'flex-start'}}>
                    <Item style={{borderBottomWidth: 0, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems:'flex-start'}}>
                    <Button
                  style={{
                    paddingTop: 0, 
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)', 
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                    alignItems:'flex-start', 
                    textAlign: 'left', 
                    marginBottom: 1,
                    marginTop:0,
                    elevation:0,
                  }}
                  onPress={() => {
                  let { Textdata } = this.state;
                  Textdata[index] = item.TakeProfitThree;
                  this.copyValue(JSON.stringify(this.state.Textdata[index]))
                }}>
                      <Text style={styles.valueBoxLabel}><Icon style={styles.miniIcon} active name='checkmark-circle-outline' />  TP-3</Text>
                      <Text style={styles.valueBox}>{item.TakeProfitThree}   <Icon style={styles.miniIcon} active name='copy' /></Text>
                      </Button>
                    </Item>                    
                  </Item>
                </Col>
              </Grid>
              </Item>

              <Item style={{borderBottomWidth: 0, marginTop: 10, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <Button
                style={{
                  paddingTop: 3,
                  paddingBottom: 3,
                  height: 28,
                  alignSelf: 'center',
                  textAlign: 'center',
                  backgroundColor: '#e05e55'
                }}
                >
                  <Text>Cerrar</Text>
                </Button>
              </Item>

            </Col>
          </Grid>
        </CardItem>
        <LinearGradient
      colors={['#006396', '#192f6a']}
      start={[0,1]}
      end={[1,0]}
      >
        <CardItem style={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)', paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight:0, paddingTop:0,paddingBottom:0}}>
          <Accordion
          dataArray={[
            { title: <Text style={{color: '#fff'}}>Ver historial de movimientos</Text>,
            content: 
            item.History.map((item, key) => {
              return (
                <Text key={key} style={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)' ,paddingTop: 0, color: '#fff', borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'}}>
                  {item.ModifiedDate}:{"\n"}{item.Message}{"\n"}{"\n"}
                </Text>
              );
            })
          }
          ]}
          headerStyle={{backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)", borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'}}
          contentStyle={{paddingTop: 10, backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)", color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)', paddingLeft: 15, paddingRight: 15}}
          style={{backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)', width: '100%'}}
          iconStyle={{ color: "white" }}
          icon="arrow-down"
          expandedIcon="arrow-up"
          iconStyle={{ color: "#fff" }}
          expandedIconStyle={{ color: "#fff" }}
          />              
        </CardItem>
        </LinearGradient>
      </LinearGradient>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );

}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getHomeSignals(); 
    this.getHistorySignals();
}

static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Welcome',
};

comingSoon() {
  Toast.show({
    text: 'Aún no está disponible esta sección',
    buttonText: "Okay",
    duration: 3000,
  });
}

render() {
  const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;

  if (!this.state.isReady) {
    return <ActivityIndicator />
  }
   return (        
    <Root>
    <Container style={{backgroundColor: '#012435'}}>
    <LinearGradient
      colors={['#002d44', '#002d44', '#002d44']}
      start={[3,0]}
      end={[0,2]}
      >
    <Header 
    hasTabs 
    style={styles.header}
    iosBarStyle="light-content"
    androidStatusBarColor="#2c3e50"
    >
      <Left>
        <Button
            transparent
            onPress={() => navigate('Home')}
        >
          <Icon name='arrow-back' />  
        </Button>
      </Left>
      <Body>
        <Title style={styles.whiteText}>TEOS</Title>
      </Body>
      <Right>
      </Right>
    </Header>
    </LinearGradient>
    <Tabs
    tabContainerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 2, borderBottomColor: '#006396' }}
    style={Platform.OS === 'android' ? { overflow: 'hidden' } : null}>
      <Tab heading={ <TabHeading style={{backgroundColor: '#002d44'}}><Icon name="stats" style={{marginRight: 10, color: '#fff'}} /><Text style={Platform.OS === 'android' ? {color: '#fff'} : {color: '#fff'}}>Señales</Text></TabHeading>}>
        <LinearGradient
      colors={['#012435', '#012435']}
      start={[3,0]}
      end={[0,2]}
      style={{flex: 1}}
      >          
      <FlatList 
          data={this.state.dataSourceHomeSignals}
          onRefresh={() => this.onRefreshHome()}
          refreshing={this.state.isFetching}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={3}
          windowSize={2}           
          updateCellsBatchingPeriod={3}   
          initialNumToRender={6}
          />
      </LinearGradient>
      </Tab>
      <Tab heading={ <TabHeading style={{backgroundColor: '#002d44'}}><Icon name="paper" style={{marginRight: 10, color: '#fff'}} /><Text style={Platform.OS === 'android' ? {color: '#fff'} : {color: '#fff'}}>Historial</Text></TabHeading>}>
      <LinearGradient
      colors={['#012435', '#012435']}
      start={[3,0]}
      end={[0,2]}
      style={{flex: 1}}
      >          
      <FlatList 
          data={this.state.dataSourceHistorySignals}
          onRefresh={() => this.onRefreshHistory()}
          refreshing={this.state.isFetching}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={3}
          windowSize={2}           
          updateCellsBatchingPeriod={3}   
          initialNumToRender={6}
          onEndReachedThreshold={1}
          />
      </LinearGradient>
      </Tab>
    </Tabs>
    <Footer style={{backgroundColor:"rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)", borderTopWidth: 2, borderTopColor: '#006396'}}>
      <FooterTab style={{backgroundColor:"#012435"}}>
        <Button 
          onPress={() => navigate('Home')}
          vertical>
          <Icon style={{color: '#fff'}} name="home" />
          <Text style={{color: '#fff'}}>Inicio</Text>
        </Button>
        <Button
          style={{backgroundColor: '#006396', borderRadius: 0}}
          vertical>
          <Icon style={{color: '#fff'}} name="trending-up" />
          <Text style={{color: '#fff'}}>Señales</Text>
        </Button>
        <Button 
          onPress={() => {
            this.comingSoon()
          }}
          vertical>
          <Icon style={{color: '#fff'}} name="walk" />
          <Text style={{color: '#fff'}}>Deportes</Text>
        </Button>
        <Button 
          onPress={() => {
            this.comingSoon()
          }}
          vertical>
          <Icon style={{color: '#fff'}} name="flash" />
          <Text style={{color: '#fff'}}>Crypto</Text>
        </Button>
      </FooterTab>
    </Footer>
  </Container>
  </Root>

      );

}
}
```

I expect the item to change it's style onPress smoothly, without a big delay. But I'm getting a 3-4 seconds lag

Comment: same. Did you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

This issue you're running into is that your `FlatList` depends on data other than the `data` prop - i.e. your `renderItem` also uses `this.state.selectedSignal`. So the `FlatList` doesn't know it needs to re-render when `this.state.selectedSignal` changes. Use the `extraData` [1] property to tell `FlatList` about additional data that `renderItem` depends on:

```
<FlatList 
          data={this.state.dataSourceHistorySignals}
          onRefresh={() => this.onRefreshHistory()}
          refreshing={this.state.isFetching}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={3}
          windowSize={2}           
          updateCellsBatchingPeriod={3}   
          initialNumToRender={6}
          onEndReachedThreshold={1}
          extraData={this.state.selectedSignal}
          />
```

[1] https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#extradata

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I already added that property and nothing changed at all

Comment: Can you include how you're using `extraData` in your post in that case? A delay of 3-4 seconds on re-render sounds a lot like the FlatList is just not re-rendering, unless you're also seeing an initial render time of the FlatList of 3-4 seconds.

Comment: For example, adding the "extraData" property, actually doesn't re render, but is weird cause it does only with the first two elements. I added this "selectedSignal={!!this.state.selectedSignal}" to my _renderItem function and "extraData={this.state.selectedSignal}" to my Flatlist

Answer (score 0):

The real issue for the list rendering slow even when you have a small set of data is because how each item is created in the data array. Like it could created as a new object which makes the whole data array as something "new" which flatlist rerenders all element for. Like when you do "selected" on an item, the flatlist data array changes making flatlist render all the items once again even when they are the same.

The way to get around this is to use reselect (https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) which reuses object references when the data has not changed.